# How to remove empty dataframes in a list before using bind_rows()?

Tags: r

I have a list of a mix of dataframes, tibble and empty list. How do I remove the tibble and empty list before applying `bind_rows` to append the rest of the data frames?

I tried using the `delete.NULLs` function but there was an error:

> Error: could not find function "delete.NULLs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @akrun data:

```
lst1[unlist(lapply(lst1, function(x) !(is.null(x) | is_tibble(x))))]
```

Regarding your question about `NA`:

```
lst1 <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1:3), NULL, tibble(col1 = 1:5, 
                                                  col2 = 2:6), data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6), NA)

lst <-lst1[unlist(lapply(lst1, function(x) !(is.null(x) | is_tibble(x))))]

lst<-lst[!is.na(lst)]
```

Comment: in what situation will your code differ from akrun's one?

Comment: None, it is just another way to solve your problem.

Comment: that solved the na and the tibble issue, but i realised in my list there is a 'logical' type with data 'NA'. how can I also delete that?

Comment: I addressed that in my second part.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `discard`

```
library(purrr)
discard( lst1, ~is.vector(.x) || is.null(.x)|is_tibble(.x) )
```

EDIT: From @ArtemSokolov's comments

---

Or from `base R`

```
out <-  Filter(function(x) !(is.vector(x) | is.null(x) |is_tibble(x)), lst1)
out
#[[1]]
#  col1
#1    1
#2    2
#3    3

#[[2]]
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#3 3 4
#4 4 5
#5 5 6
```

---

The `delete.NULLs` function is not found in `base R`. But, it could be created with a combination of `is.null` and negate (`!`).

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1:3), NULL, tibble(col1 = 1:5, 
             col2 = 2:6), NA, data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6))
```

Comment: that solved the na and the tibble issue, but i realised in my list there is a 'logical' type with data 'NA'. how can I also delete that?

Comment: @Jein would be better to show a small reproudicble example.  Did you meant a list value of only `NA`

Comment: @akrun: You don't need `map_lgl` inside discard. Use your predicate formula directly as the second argument: `discard( lst1, ~is.null(.x)|is_tibble(.x) )`